# Rails server command bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, server

I started a new ruby-on-rails project called "myrubyblog", changed directories to my project then launched `rails server` command, but the terminal then outputs me this after an incredible amount of lines of information I don't understand;

```
-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bin/rails

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/enc/encdb.so
    5 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/enc/trans/transdb.so
    6 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/rbconfig.rb
    7 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    8 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    9 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
   10 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/errors.rb
   11 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/version.rb
   12 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   13 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   14 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   15 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   16 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/util/list.rb
   17 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/stringio.so
   18 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb
   19 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb
   20 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/common.rb
   21 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/generic.rb
   22 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/ftp.rb
   23 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/http.rb
   24 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/https.rb
   25 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/ldap.rb
   26 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   27 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/mailto.rb
   28 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri.rb
   29 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   30 /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb

... (up to 320 lines)

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abandon
```

What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: What ruby version are you running? `ruby --version`

Comment: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [armv7l-linux-eabihf]

Comment: What happen if you downgrade the ruby version?

Comment: What is the command that you used to create the Rails project?